# Can't get jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, struts2

I want to use jQuery datepicker in my Struts app

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My First JQuery Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mytestcss.css">
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="formdiv">
    <s:form>
        <s:textfield label="username" name="username" ></s:textfield>
        <s:password label="password" name="password" ></s:password>
        <s:textfield label="date" id="datepicker" name="date"></s:textfield>
        
    </s:form>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>
</html>
```

Did I miss anything?
Why datepicker is not loading?

Comment: What does the console say ?

Comment: thanks for the alert! The .js file was not loaded ,because of **/js/jquery-1.11.1.js** i changed it to  **js/jquery-1.11.1.js** (removed '/')

Comment: @singe31 why can't get because of '/' ?

Comment: `/` is the root. So either write `./js/jquery-1.11.1.js` or `js/jquery-1.11.1.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My First JQuery Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mytestcss.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="formdiv">
    <s:form>
        <s:textfield label="username" name="username" ></s:textfield>
        <s:password label="password" name="password" ></s:password>
        <s:textfield label="date" id="datepicker" name="date"></s:textfield>

    </s:form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The .js file was not loaded ,because of /js/jquery-1.11.1.js i changed it to js/jquery-1.11.1.js (removed '/')

Comment: @AleksandrM can't get you .. edit in my code .Are you asking me to set id's for each form elements?

Comment: No. Id must be unique. You have two elements with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `s:url` tag to build correct path

```
<script src="<s:url value='/js/jquery-1.11.1.js'/>"></script>
```

JSTL `c:url` tag works similar

```
<script src="<c:url value='/js/jquery-1.11.1.js'/>"></script>
```

or use JSP EL

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use document ready event to be sure your element is rendered

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: using $(function() { }) or $(document).ready(function() {}) is one and the same thing...

Comment: @Bily,@Exception  thanks for ur response error was due to ,because of **/js/jquery-1.11.1.js** i changed it to **js/jquery-1.11.1.js** (removed '/')  why can't get because of '/' ?

Comment: The difference is that when you use / in front of the path it is an absolute path. If you use the path without / - it is a relative one.

Comment: if i am specifying as /webcontent/js/myjsfile.js is it correct path from root?